# Reverse array isn't in sequence

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I trying to reverse the elements in an array. For example, I got :

```
    15 69 94 52 97 51 17 18 50 18
```

And it would be in :

```
    18 50 18 17 51 97 52 94 69 15 (which is reversed)
```

However, this is what I get from my code :

```
    51 69 94 52 97 17 18 50 18 15 (the sequence are jumbled out which I have no idea why)
```

And here is my code :

```
     void reverse(int num_array[], const int& size);
int main ()
{
const int size = 10;
int num_array[size];

srand (time(NULL));

for (int count = 0; count< size ; count++){
    /* generate secret number between 1 and 100: */
    num_array[count] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << num_array[count] << " " ;
}

reverse(num_array,size);

cout << "\n\n" ;
for(int index = 0; index< size; index++){
    cout << num_array[index] << " " ;
}

cout << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void reverse(int num_array[], const int& size)
{
for (int count =0; count< size/2; count++){
    int temp = num_array[0];
    num_array[0] = num_array[size-count-1];
    num_array[size-count-1] = temp;
}
}
```

I guess there is something wrong in my reverse method. Can somebody please fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there is `std::reverse` for this purpose. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Ya I knew but for this time, I am required to use swapping as my teacher mentioned. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean `num_array[count]` instead of `num_array[0]`, I assume.

Comment: Oh ya that's cool. It's solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can accept his answer to provide him with precious karma :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(int num_array[], const int& size)
{
 for (int count =0; count< size/2; count++){
 int temp = num_array[count];
 num_array[count] = num_array[size-count-1];
 num_array[size-count-1] = temp;
 }
}
```

will give right output.